# Formik and arrayField integration with material ui

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

[image]

I'm trying to build a formik/material ui framework -- but the array field structure doesn't seem to be working properly.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-albattani-ztf10

When  you try and add a 3rd friend and start typing -- I get the error "trying to control uncontrolled" issue?

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

-- in these docs though I don't see this error?
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/formik/formik/tree/master/examples/field-arrays?from-embed=&file=/index.js
https://formik.org/docs/examples/field-arrays

------------- -- this was using useformik  and didn't work with the arrayfields

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-kare-ixonw

when I click on "Add Member" -- the error "Cannot read property 'setFormikState' of undefined" shows up

I've tried following these examples - but I am unsure what is causing this error.
https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray

I've tried using fieldArrayHelper - but it doesn't seem to take

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-kare-ixonw?file=/src/_Globals/GeneralFormik/FieldHandler.js

Comment: The issue i see here is you are using `useFormik` which is a hook in a class component thats quite strange , useFormik hook was meant to be used in the functional components . What you can do instead is to use the `Formik` component .

Comment: All the fields appear to work - but this add array - not really sure how to build it - without these errors - or what these errors are about

Comment: Its like you need to set the initial vals -- and it comes into error when that object changes?

Comment: it appears the initial values need to be set --- I had to not use arrayhelpers in the end

Comment: In the documentation they don't use initial values for dynamic fields: https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray

Comment: they did? initialValues={{ friends: ['jared', 'ian', 'brent'] }}

Comment: I expressed myself wrongly, sorry. They don't "update" initial values after add new field.

Comment: I got it working by using these {({ insert, remove, push }) => (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when inputs are receiving `undefined` values, which React interprets to mean the inputs are uncontrolled. You can see that here https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/28.

So what you need is init a friend value when click `Add a Friend` like this (`FieldArrayHandler.js`)

```
<Button
   disabled={parent.disabled}
   variant="contained"
   color="primary"
   type="button"
   onClick={() =>
     arrayHelpers.push({ firstName: "", lastName: "" })
   }
>
   Add a friend
</Button>
```

And you can see a demo working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-black-5l7zt?file=/src/_Globals/GeneralFormik/FieldArrayHandler.js:4290-4332)